# How to make enormous/many http.request without reaching TCP limit?

Tags: node.js, tcp

I am using NodeJS server for HTTP request when request for a period with request per second, around 500 request, HTTP request in server stop working, when I open up netsat, TCP port on previous request didnt close, it is the reason causing the problem.

Is there any way to close TCP request port? or can I reuse the same TCP port for making request?

Comment: Are you using req.end() on the end of the request?

Comment: What OS are you on? This is a common problem on MacOS because the OS will delay closing sockets even after both sides have closed the socket. So on a Mac a network app will pause for roughly 15 seconds (the socket close delay) periodically. No other OS have this problem to the best of my knowledge

Comment: yes, I have req.end() on the end of the request and in macOS, I will try on the window now, thank you!

Comment: After trying on the window, the netstat still show many TCP port opened, and the request is stopped by open too many TCP ports.

How to avoid this? I can't find any way to close the TCP by NodeJS, or if there any way to reuse the same port?